# Default index analyzer in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am facing a problem with elasticsearch where I dont want my indexed term to be analyzed. But the elasticsearch has some default setting which is tokenizing it on space. 
Therefore my facet query is not returning the result I want.

I read that `"index" : "not_analyzed"` in properties of index type should work.
But the problem is that I dont know my document structure before hand. I would be indexing random MySQL databases to elasticsearch without knowing the table structure.

How can I setup elasticsearch such that by default it uses `"index" : "not_analyzed"` until otherwise asked for.
Thanks

PS: I am using java if I can directly use any API for it I would love it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'd use dynamic templates - it should do what you are looking for:

```
{
    "testtemplates" : {
        "dynamic_templates" : [
            {
                "template1" : {
                    "match" : "*",
                    "match_mapping_type" : "string",
                    "mapping" : {
                        "type" : "string",
                        "index" : "not_analyzed"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

More on this approach here:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/custom-dynamic-mapping.html#dynamic-templates

**Important:**
If someone suggest this approach to solve the *not_analyzed* issue, it will not work!
*keyword* analyzer does some analyzing on the data and convert the data to small letters.

e.g. 
`Data: ElasticSearchRocks ==> Keyword Analyzer: elasticsearchrocks`

Try it yourself with analyzing query and see it happening.

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/testindex -d '{
    "index" : {
        "analysis" : {
            "analyzer" : {
                "default" : {
                    "type" : "keyword"
                }
            }
       }
    }
}'
```

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keyword-analyzer.html

Comment: especially useful if you use this on the default mapping: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/default-mapping.html

Comment: The dynamic mapping template docs have moved: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/custom-dynamic-mapping.html#dynamic-templates (edit: oh, went ahead and edited the answer directly.. who reads comments any way :P)

Answer (score 6):

add `index.analysis.analyzer.default.type: keyword` in your `elasticsearch.yml`.