# How to create a Elasticsearch node specifying default search analyzers for indexing and searching

Tags: java, elasticsearch

The [Elasticsearch documents](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-analyzers.html) state the following:

> The default logical name allows one to configure an analyzer that will be used both for indexing and for searching APIs. The default_index logical name can be used to configure a default analyzer that will be used just when indexing, and the default_search can be used to configure a default analyzer that will be used just when searching.

In other words, it is possible to configure a default analyzer used when *indexing*, and another used when *searching*.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23366602/default-index-analyzer-in-elasticsearch) and its answer helped me to create a node with a default analyzer for *indexing*, which (simplified) can programmatically be done like this:

```
public Node node() {
    ImmutableSettings.Builder elasticsearchSettings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder()
      .put("index.analysis.analyzer.default.type", "keyword");
    return NodeBuilder.nodeBuilder()
      .settings(elasticsearchSettings.build())
      .node();
}
```

What would be the equivalent way of specifying the default analyzer to be used when *searching*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the default analyzers can be defined using:

- `index.analysis.analyzer.default_index.type` for indexing
- `index.analysis.analyzer.default_search.type` for searching

Comment: Ah, I think I get it. `index.analysis.analyzer.default.type` actually sets the default analyzer for __both__ indexing and searching, while the above can be used to set different analyzers?

Comment: That's my understanding, yes.