# ElasticSearch aggregation: String with spaces treat as two strings

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using this query in order to get which values there are in a single field (SQLfying would be a `SELECT field, count(field) GROUP BY field`.

In order to do that I'm sending this request to ES:

```
{
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : {
        "exists" : {
          "field" : "metainfos.ceeaacceaeaaccebeaacceceaaccedeaac"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "followUpActivity.metainfo.metainfos.ceeaacceaeaaccebeaacceceaaccedeaac" : {
      "terms" : {
        "field" : "metainfos.ceeaacceaeaaccebeaacceceaaccedeaac",
        "missing" : "null"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

There's only one document on this collection:

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "living_v1",
      "_type" : "fuas",
      "_id" : "a2cb0ba1-8955-11e6-8a00-0242ac110007",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_routing" : "user2",
      "_source" : {
        "user" : "user2",
        "timestamp" : "2016-10-03T11:08:30.074Z",
        "startTimestamp" : "2016-10-03T11:08:30.074Z",
        "dueTimestamp" : null,
        "closingTimestamp" : null,
        "matter" : "Fua 1",
        "comment" : null,
        "status" : 0,
        "backlogStatus" : 20,
        "metainfos" : {
          "ceeaacceaeaaccebeaacceceaaccedeaac" : [ "Living Digital" ]
        },
        "resources" : [ ],
        "notes" : null
      }
    } ]
  }
}
```

As you can see `doc.metainfos.ceeaacc... = ["Living Digital"]`

```
{
  "took" : 3,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "living_v1",
      "_type" : "fuas",
      "_id" : "a2cb0ba1-8955-11e6-8a00-0242ac110007",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_routing" : "user2",
      "_source":{"user":"user2","timestamp":"2016-10-03T11:08:30.074Z","startTimestamp":"2016-10-03T11:08:30.074Z","dueTimestamp":null,"closingTimestamp":null,"matter":"Fua 1","comment":null,"status":0,"backlogStatus":20,"metainfos":{"ceeaacceaeaaccebeaacceceaaccedeaac":["Living Digital"]},"resources":[],"notes":null}
    } ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "followUpActivity.metainfo.metainfos.ceeaacceaeaaccebeaacceceaaccedeaac" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [ {
        "key" : "digital",
        "doc_count" : 1
      }, {
        "key" : "living",
        "doc_count" : 1
      } ]
    }
  }
}
```

ES is getting me two values: one for `"living"` and another one for `"digital"`. I'd like to get aggregation using the shole values `"Living Digital"`.

The mapping scheme is:

```
{
  "living_v1" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "fuas" : {
        "properties" : {
          "backlogStatus" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "comment" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "matter" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "metainfos" : {
            "properties" : {
              "ceeaacceaeaaccebeaacceceaaccedeaac" : {
                "type" : "string"
              }
            }
          },
          "startTimestamp" : {
            "type" : "date",
            "format" : "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
          },
          "status" : {
            "type" : "long"
          },
          "timestamp" : {
            "type" : "date",
            "format" : "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
          },
          "user" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "index" : "not_analyzed"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see:

```
"metainfos" : {
    "properties" : {
        "ceeaacceaeaaccebeaacceceaaccedeaac" : {
             "type" : "string"
         }
     }
 }
```

The problem for me is "ceeaacceaeaaccebeaacceceaaccedeaac" is a user on-demand property created and I don't know how could I set an `not-analyzed` to any `metainfos.*` field.

**EDIT**

I've tested with:

```
#curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/living_v1/' -d '
{
  "mappings": {
    "fuas": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "metainfos": {
            "path_match":   "metainfos.*",
            "match_mapping_type": "string",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
'
```

It's telling me that `living_v1` index already exist. As far I've been able to figure out on [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/custom-dynamic-mapping.html#dynamic-templates) I need to send a `PUT` against `index`:

```
{
    "error":{
    "root_cause":[
        {
            "type":"index_already_exists_exception",
            "reason":"already exists",
            "index":"living_v1"
        }
    ],
    "type":"index_already_exists_exception",
    "reason":"already exists",
    "index":"living_v1"
},
"status":400
}
```

Comment: I think you are looking for dynamic index templates: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23370138/693546

Comment: You can't update the mapping for anything that already has data. You may need to create a new index with the fixed mapping, then reindex your data to this index. Then you could delete the old index and use it's name as a alias for the new index.

Comment: Another option is to add an additional field (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/multi-fields.html) (call it "raw", for instance). Then you can aggregate on "ceeaacceaeaaccebeaacceceaaccedeaac.raw" instead, while preserving the mapping of "ceeaacceaeaaccebeaacceceaaccedeaac". I think this will only affect documents that are indexed after you change the mappings, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already noticed, the search behaviour is caused by the mapping that was applied by default. This mapping does analyzing on all string-valued fields that are not defined differently.

So if you don't yet know which properties (=keys) will be in the `metainfos` object, you can use the dynamic templates feature as described [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html) and [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/custom-dynamic-mapping.html#dynamic-templates) to define which mapping should be applied for these fields and so override the default behaviour of analyzing a string field.

You could apply a mapping that looks a bit like this (not tested):

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "fuas": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "metainfos": {
            "path_match":   "metainfos.*",
            "match_mapping_type": "string",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed",
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Andreas. I've tried it, however it has come up some issues. What's the difference between templates and your approach? Are they the same?

Answer (score 1):

As other people have pointed out, dynamic templates is the way to go. The only problem is that you can't change index template after some documents were indexed. You will need to recreate the index (delete index, create mapping, feed new documents)

Comment: Ok @oldbam, I got it. Is there some straightforward way to recreate the index from `index_v1` to `index_v2`?

Comment: you may consider looking at answers at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28626803/how-to-rename-an-index-in-a-cluster . I always deleted an index and started feeding documents again when I was changing index template